# Backing variable not automatically synthesized for property

Tags: objective-c, xcode

In my view controller's header file I've created a property:

```
@property(nonatomic) BOOL hasPhoto;
```

In my implementation file, I want to override its setter, hence:

```
-(void)setHasPhoto:(BOOL)hasPhoto{
    _hasPhoto = hasPhoto;
    if(hasPhoto){
        //do something
    }
}
```

However, when I try to compile, Xcode doesn't see the backing variable, which should be named `_hasPhoto` and doesn't compile. If I synthesize it manually:

```
@synthesize hasPhoto = _hasPhoto;
```

It works. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you overridden the getter method as well? Then this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13817562/property-not-working-with-getter-and-setter.

Comment: @MartinR no, I haven't overridden the getter. The code in the question is all the (relevant) code.

Comment: That's strange. Your code compiles without problem for me. Can you show a (minimal) self-contained example of the .h and .m file?

Comment: Which version of Xcode? Are you using a version before 5.0?

Comment: Out of curiosity, does it compile fine if you add `@synthesize hasPhoto=_hasPhoto;` in the implementation?

Comment: @RyanR yes it does compile just fine. right now I'm actually using that to get my project working.

Comment: @gnasher729 I am on the current latest Xcode, 5.1.1

Answer (score 0):

Clang (the compiler behind Xcode) will only generate the backing ivar for a property if the property is declared in the interface for a class - otherwise [you need to synthesize it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19784454/when-should-i-use-synthesize-explicitly) or implement the methods for the property yourself. It will **not** generate the ivar for you if the property is defined in a protocol or category on the class. My guess is that you have declared the property in a protocol, in which case you will need to use `@synthesize hasPhoto=_hasPhoto`.

```
// This is just a forward declaration of the protocol
@protocol MyProto;

@interface ZZZMyController : UIViewController<MyProto>

// This property will get an ivar automatically generated
@property (nonatomic) BOOL hasPhoto;

@end

@interface ZZZMyController(ExtraStuff)

// This property will NOT get an ivar automatically, you would need to synthesize it explicitly or create your own implementations of both methods
@property (nonatomic) BOOL categoryBool;

@end

@protocol MyProto <NSObject>

// This property will NOT get an ivar automatically either, you would need to synthesize it explicitly or create your own implementations of both methods
@property (nonatomic) protoBool;

@end
```

If this answer doesn't fix your problem, I would recommend removing and reinstalling Xcode. If *that* doesn't work, file a [bug report](https://bugreport.apple.com).

Comment: Unfortunatelly, that's also not the case. The property is defined in a regular class interface in a header file with many other properties, with no problem. it is not in an M file, not in a protocol declaration, nor in a extension/category. I don't think reinstalling Xcode will change much (I've already purged the derived data and cleaned build folder, restarted Xcode etc.), I think I'll file a bug report.